# Select the maximum iterated name inside a list of names in python

Tags: python, list, counter, voting

I have a list of names, some names may be iterated. I want to make a counter for each name to select the maximum iterated one. For example my list is as follow:

```
list = ['ABC', 'BCD', 'ASD', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ZXC', 'BCD']
```

I want the program to return:

```
ABC = 4
BCD = 2
ASD = 1
ZXC = 1
```

Finally I want to select the maximum iterated name as a winner. How can I do that. Can anyone please help me, I will be thankful to him.

Comment: I added one more duplicate @CoryKramer because I wanted to make sure using `Counter.most_common` was front and center in one the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter({'ABC': 4, 'BCD': 2, 'ASD': 1, 'ZXC': 1})
# Counter({'ABC': 4, 'BCD': 2, 'ASD': 1, 'ZXC': 1})
```

And in order to obtain string with the highest amount of counts you can use the `most_common` method from the `Counter`:

```
Counter(l).most_common(1)
# [('ABC', 4)]
```

Comment: Good 'ol `collections`!

Comment: @yatu thank you very much.